# Why cant I import my package created using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am working on a project (CN_Analysis) for which I would like to create my own python package (cn_tools) using setuptools. My goal is to have it accessible everywhere in my project folder. However, when I try to import it from a subfolder (e.g. CN_Analysis/Notebooks), I get

```
(.virtualenvironment) ...:~/Workspace/CN_Analysis/Notebooks$ python3

import cn_tools
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cn_tools'
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
CN_Analysis
├──README.md\
├──requirements.txt\
├──.gitignore\
├──setup.py\
├──.virtualenvironment/\
├──Notebooks/\
├──Data/\
├──cn_tools/\
|  ├──__init__.py\
|  ├──my_tools.py
```

The contents of setup.py are:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name = 'cn_tools',
version = '0.1',
description = 'This package contains helpful functions for the processing data obtained from Karambola.',
packages=find_packages(where='cn_tools'),
package_dir={'': 'cn_tools'})
```

Additional information:
The basic routine is

```
source .virtualenvironment/bin/activate
(.virtualenvironment) python3 setup.py develop
```

Results in

```
Installed /home/ansgar/Workspace/CN_Analysis/cn_tools\
Processing dependencies for cn-tools==0.1\
Finished processing dependencies for cn-tools==0.1
```

Check for python3

```
(.virtualenvironment) which python3        

/home/my_name/Workspace/CN_Analysis/.virtualenvironment/bin/python3
```

And if I call sys.path from python after I navigated to a subfolder (e.g Notebooks/), it returns

```
 ['',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/my_name/Workspace/CN_Analysis/.virtualenvironment/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/home/my_name/Workspace/CN_Analysis/cn_tools']
```

Does someone know why I cannot import cn_tools?

Comment: try to run `python3 setup.py  install` to install the lib first

Comment: Doing that does not resolve the problem. However, I get the output\

installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I just use

packages=find_packages()

instead of

packages=find_packages(where='cn_tools')

in the setup.py file.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. I recommend that you read in your requirements.txt in your setup.py. This will ensure that you install your dependencies during setup. I can provide an answer with such addition (out of scope of the OP).

Comment: I think thats a good idea and I have one question about it. Would you recommend using the reqirements.txt with all the dependecies regarding the whole project or just those being explicitly required in the module?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do ultimately. You can lock it by doing `pip freeze > requirements-lock.txt` for this set-up/env, but I would recommend listing the main ones as those often have specific dependencies built in. The latter is easier to understand and there may be little differences between a locked one and the latest one for your needs.